# Update table2 on change of table1

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a strange requirement, I want to replicate data from table1 of Schema1 to table2 of Schema2 on any change of table1.

I am using postgres, how to achieve this? tables will have exactly same structure

Comment: Can you use triggers for this?

Comment: which column u trying to update?

Comment: all the columns should be updated on any change of data in `table1` no matter if it is `add` `delete` `update` the same operation should be replicated at `table2` I am ok to use triggers too..

Answer (score 1):

If the table in schema2 should always be an exact copy of the one in schema1, I would simply create a view in schema2 that selects from schema1.

```
create view schema2.table1
as 
select * 
from schema1.table1;
```

You will need to re-create the view if you change the definition of the table in schema1 (but you would need to do that with a replicated copy as well).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to analyze the nature of the workload and your priorities. And will become clearer in what direction to look for a solution.

For example, if you can assume that updates will occur much less frequently than deletions and additions and you have a limited time - implement just simpliest delete, insert triggers and handle update as reinsert in both tables.